# In Google Keep, how to format lines as nested bullet points?

Tags: google-keep

In Google Keep, how to format lines as nested bullet points? I understand single-level bullet points can be formatted by creating the note as a list.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you are using the web interface, you can simply use `*` to manually create bullets. Keep automatically remembers the indentation of the last bullet you created.

For example, to create the following list in Keep:

- Item 1

  - Item 2
  - Item 3

    - Item 4

You would:

1. Open a new, regular note.
2. Type `*`, `Space`, `Item 1` (this should create a new bullet from the `*`)  and then press `Enter`.
3. On the next line, `Backspace` to remove the automatically created bullet point, then indent e.g. four spaces (the exact amount of indentation would be based on your preferences).
4. Remaining on the same line, type `*` again then `Item 2` and press `Enter`.
5. A new, automatically created bullet should appear below and in-line with the bullet for `Item 2`. You would then type `Item 3` and again press `Enter`.
6. `Item 4` would be based on repeating Steps 3-5, just with different indentation (e.g. eight spaces).

**Notes**

- This behavior isn't directly available from the Chrome extension (as far a I am aware). That is, if you right-click the Keep icon in Chrome and select *New blank note*, the interface that pops up for the new note doesn't appear to support translating `*` into bullets.
- This manual method does work for the Keep Android app.

Comment: Something really annoying me with this is the indent is lost if you go beyond a single line.